# PHP action / salesForce

Tags: php, ajax, forms, validation, salesforce

I have been asked to update a contact form, i always leave action blank(action="") in any forms i have worked on before. I have been sent the following form as seen below. When the form is submitted, it is sent to the url, which is a blank screen. Has anyone implemented a salesForce contact form before ?

```
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

  <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D200000005wgb">
  <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://"> <!--  add URL of completed page here
```

-->

```
   <label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

   <label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

   <label for="email">Email Address</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>

   <label for="phone">Phone</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /><br>

     <select id="country" name="country" title="country">
       <option value="London">London</option>
       <option value="Midlands">Midlands</option>
       <option value="North England">North England</option>
       <option value="South England">South England</option>
       <option value="Wales">Wales</option>
       <option value="Scotland">Scotland</option>
       <option value="Northern Ireland">Northern Ireland</option>
     </select><br>


     <textarea id="00N200000016Kk5" name="00N200000016Kk5" rows="4" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>

      <!-- Below 3 fields are hidden  -->
      <select id="recordType" name="recordType" style="display:none;">
        <option value="012w0000000QCbe">Prospect UK</option></select>
        <select id="00N20000001L8Pi" name="00N20000001L8Pi" title="Web Source" style="display:none;"><option value="Download Whitepapers UK">Download Whitepapers UK</option>    </select>  
      <select id="lead_source" name="lead_source" style="display:none;">
      <option value="Download Whitepapers UK">Download Whitepapers UK</option></select>


      <input type="submit" name="submit">

   </form>
```

Comment: So the question is if anyone has used a salesForce contact form before?...

Comment: What does the action do? when i click submit the form directs to that url.. im not sure what action does? and if anyone has used salesForce guidance on what i should be doing to make the form work

Comment: Ok I will provide you with an answer.  One moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `action` attribute of a `<form>` is basically a redirect for the form that sends the POST or GET data along with it.

1. If action is left blank, it redirects to the current URL, thus "refreshes".
2. If action is a link beginning with `http://` **or** `https://`, the form sends the `$_POST` / `$_GET` request to the full page link.
3. If action is set to a link not beginning with `http://` nor `https://`, the link set in the action is added to the current sub-directory in the same way a php include works.

Therefore, this in your code:

```
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
```

Will send a POST request to `https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8`

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful. If i drop the html above into my contact page and run that page, should the code work as required, or would additional code be required to make this form submit? when i click submit the form directs to the action url and that is where the user is directed

Comment: No, that should work as long as there is a submit button.  Then, you just grab the information with php.

Comment: What information should i be collecting with php and where should that information be going to, as i assume the action is collecting the data and storing it there?

Comment: Whatever information you sent in the form (since you are using a post request) will be stored in the new `$_POST` array when the page refreshes and it has all the submitted inputs in it.  For example, what the user wrote as their first name will be stored in the new `$_POST['first_name']` variable because `first_name` was set as the `name` attribute of the input sent through the form.  As for how you can use this, you can store it in a database, or use it for basically any purpose you want.  Also, if you wanted to know all post requests sent, you would use `print_r($_POST);` which echoes them.

Comment: would u know any tutorials that would link me to a contact form that i could just drop my code into with a few tweaks as every time i click submit button my page is directing to the action url and thats all. So annoying